# Javascript auto submit not executing after printer script runs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a javascript novice.  I have a printer function called sendToQuickPrinter() and it prints fine, but when that script finishes, I need to auto submit form to get back to my "cart.php" page.  I think i'm real close.  Please help.

```
<script>

function sendToQuickPrinter(){

    var text =
    "<CENTER><MEDIUM2><?php echo $shop_name ?><BR>" +
    "<CENTER><?php echo $display_date ?>        <?php echo $display_time ?><BR><BR>" +
    "Description          Price<BR>" +
    "<?php $i=0;while($i < $print_count){$i=$i+1; echo $p_name_array[$i].';; ;;'.$transaction_qty_array[$i].' @ '.number_format($p_price_array[$i],2).'<BR>';} ?>" +
    "<BR>" +
    "<CENTER>Sub-total      $<?php echo number_format($subtotal,2) ?><BR>" +
    "<CENTER>Tax            $<?php echo number_format($subtax,2) ?><BR>" +
    "<CENTER>Total          $<?php echo number_format($item_total,2) ?><BR>" +
    "<BR>" +
    "<CENTER>Thank you for shopping with us, we appreciate your business!<BR>" +
    "<CENTER><MEDIUM2> Have a great day!<BR>" +
    "<BR>" +
    "<CUT>" +
    "DRAWER";
        var textEncoded = encodeURI(text);
        window.location.href="quickprinter://"+textEncoded;

        document.frm2.submit()  // !!!important- I auto submit frm2 below
}

sendToQuickPrinter();

</script>

<form  action="cart.php" name="frm2" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon" />
    <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="<?php echo $shop_name ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: you mean that you need to redirect to cart.php when print function finishes?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: do any of following answers work for you?

Comment: Im working on it, I will let you know

Comment: They were all great idea's but not what I was looking for so far

Comment: try to move `window.location.href="quickprinter://"+textEncoded;`after `document.frm2.submit()`

Comment: Still doesnt work.  if I call document.frm1.submit() then it does not print and goes to the re-direct page.  But if I omit document.frm1.submit() then it prints, but the page does not re-direct.

Answer (score 0):

Change `document.frm2.submit()` with `document.forms["frm2"].submit()`

```
function sendToQuickPrinter(){

  var text =
  "<CENTER><MEDIUM2><?php echo $shop_name ?><BR>" +
  "<CENTER><?php echo $display_date ?>        <?php echo $display_time ?><BR><BR>" +
  "Description          Price<BR>" +
  "<?php $i=0;while($i < $print_count){$i=$i+1; echo $p_name_array[$i].';; ;;'.$transaction_qty_array[$i].' @ '.number_format($p_price_array[$i],2).'<BR>';} ?>" +
  "<BR>" +
  "<CENTER>Sub-total      $<?php echo number_format($subtotal,2) ?><BR>" +
  "<CENTER>Tax            $<?php echo number_format($subtax,2) ?><BR>" +
  "<CENTER>Total          $<?php echo number_format($item_total,2) ?><BR>" +
  "<BR>" +
  "<CENTER>Thank you for shopping with us, we appreciate your business!<BR>" +
  "<CENTER><MEDIUM2> Have a great day!<BR>" +
  "<BR>" +
  "<CUT>" +
  "DRAWER";
    var textEncoded = encodeURI(text);
    window.location.href="quickprinter://"+textEncoded;

    document.forms["frm2"].submit()  // !!!important- I auto submit frm2 below
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your script to before `</body>` tag or below the `form` it will work.

```js
    
    function sendToQuickPrinter(){
    
        var text =
        "<CENTER><MEDIUM2><?php echo $shop_name ?><BR>" +
        "<CENTER><?php echo $display_date ?>        <?php echo $display_time ?><BR><BR>" +
        "Description          Price<BR>" +
        "<?php $i=0;while($i < $print_count){$i=$i+1; echo $p_name_array[$i].';; ;;'.$transaction_qty_array[$i].' @ '.number_format($p_price_array[$i],2).'<BR>';} ?>" +
        "<BR>" +
        "<CENTER>Sub-total      $<?php echo number_format($subtotal,2) ?><BR>" +
        "<CENTER>Tax            $<?php echo number_format($subtax,2) ?><BR>" +
        "<CENTER>Total          $<?php echo number_format($item_total,2) ?><BR>" +
        "<BR>" +
        "<CENTER>Thank you for shopping with us, we appreciate your business!<BR>" +
        "<CENTER><MEDIUM2> Have a great day!<BR>" +
        "<BR>" +
        "<CUT>" +
        "DRAWER";
            var textEncoded = encodeURI(text);
            window.location.href="quickprinter://"+textEncoded;
    
            document.frm2.submit()  // !!!important- I auto submit frm2 below
    }
    
    //sendToQuickPrinter();
```

```html
<form  action="cart.php" name="frm2" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon" />
        <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat" />
        <input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="<?php echo $shop_name ?>" />
    </form>
    
    <button id="print" click="sendToQuickPrinter();">Print</button>
```

Comment: It re-directs the page now, but appears the sendToQuickPrinter() is not executing as the printer does not print.  I now have the reverse problem

Comment: you need add a button and assign sendToQuickPrinter to it

Comment: Thais my problem, I don't want a button here.  This is a finalize button I pressed on the previous page that is calling this page to update a database, print the receipt and then re-direct to cart.php seamlessly